# AngularJS - Displaying Date Data For Items Only In The Last Five Years

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a `$scope.myData` object that contains a list of addresses and dates that i've own/rented, eg:

```
Example of my data
From Date 2011 To Date current
From Date 2010 To Date 2011
From Date 2009 To Date 2010
From Date 2003 To Date 2004
```

What i am trying to do is output a **statement** that displays the years that i have owned/rented in the last 5 years.

**JS:**

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';

  $scope.myData = {

    "Entries": [{
        "EntryNumber": "E1",
        "FromDt": "/Date(1320912000000)/",
        "ToDt": null,
        "RegisteredWith": "test"

      }, {
        "EntryNumber": "A1",
        "FromDt": "/Date(1276153200000)/",
        "ToDt": "/Date(1320912000000)/",
        "RegisteredWith": "test"

      }, {
        "EntryNumber": "X1",
        "FromDt": "/Date(1239346800000)/",
        "ToDt": "/Date(1276153200000)/",
        "RegisteredWith": "test"

      }, {
        "EntryNumber": "Z1",
        "FromDt": "/Date(1063177200000)/",
        "ToDt": "/Date(1086850800000)/",
        "RegisteredWith": "test"
      }

    ]
  }

});
```

**HTML:**

```
<p>
    In the last 5 years i have had addresses during (from {{ myData.Entries.FromDt.substring(6,  myData.Entries.FromDt.length - 2) | date:'yyyy' }} to {{ }}, {{ }} to {{ }}, {{ }} to {{ }} and {{ }} to {{ }}).

</p>
```

**Example of expected output:**

```
<p>
    In the last 5 years i have had addresses during (from 2011 to current, 2010 to 2011 and 2009 to 2010)

</p>
```

Here's a plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/N55Zlb2ahjgovoVwTV63?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you need to use a `filter` and `ng-repeat` on a `<span>`. Your logic is largely correct in your `ng-repeat` of `<li>`s. You can just move that into a `<span>` to keep everything between your parentheses.

index.html:

```
<p>
    In the last 5 years i have had addresses during (<span ng-repeat="data in myData.Entries | filter:onlyLastFiveYears"> -from {{ parseDate(data.FromDt) }} to {{ parseDate(data.ToDt) }}</span>)
</p>
```

app.js:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  // ...

  $scope.parseDate = function(date) {
    return ((date === null && 'current') || new Date(parseInt(date.substring(6,  date.length - 2))).getFullYear())
  }

  $scope.onlyLastFiveYears = function(data) {
    var currentYear = new Date().getFullYear();
    var houseYear = $scope.parseDate(data.FromDt);
    return (currentYear - houseYear <= 5);
  }

});
```

I've edited your plunkr [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/DcSGjDUbNEcuzyKKZKxW). Good luck!

Comment: great response, does what the questions asks, im not sure its the most efficient??

Comment: There are usually many ways to accomplish the same task in AngularJS. You're right that you could use a separate filter or extract some of this logic into a service or factory. I was trying to offer a simple solution here.